# Grouping with JSON SharePoint Online Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json

I want to group the following Gallery View after status, but I don't know how to and where I need to insert the "groupProps".

Can you help me. Here is the JSON code. I tried to insert it at the beginning and at the end. It won't work.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 196,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Author.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "display": "flex"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "sp-card-userEmptyText"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=if(length([$Author]) == 0, '–', '')"
                  },
                  {
                    "forEach": "personIterator in [$Author]",
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'sp-card-userContainer', 'sp-card-userContainer sp-card-keyboard-focusable')"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') >= 5, 'none', '')"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                          "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                          "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(length([$Author]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') >= 4, 'none', '')"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-userOthers"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(length([$Author]) > 5 && loopIndex('personIterator') == 4, '', 'none')"
                        },
                        "customCardProps": {
                          "formatter": {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "sp-card-personCallout"
                            },
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "forEach": "personIterator in [$Author]",
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "attributes": {
                                  "class": "sp-card-userContainer sp-card-userCustomCard"
                                },
                                "style": {
                                  "display": "=if(loopIndex('personIterator') < 4, 'none', '')"
                                },
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "elmType": "img",
                                    "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                                    "attributes": {
                                      "src": "=getUserImage([$personIterator.email], 'S')",
                                      "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                                      "class": "sp-card-userThumbnail"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "openOnEvent": "hover"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "txtContent": "='+' + toString(length([$Author]) - (4))"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "sp-card-userTitle"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "=if(length([$Author]) == 1, '', 'none')"
                    },
                    "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]",
                    "txtContent": "[$Author.title]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Title.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
                },
                "txtContent": "[!Status.DisplayName]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-content "
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "p",
                    "txtContent": "=if(length([$Status]) == 0, '–', '')"
                  },
                  {
                    "forEach": "lookupIterator in [$Status]",
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "attributes": {
                      "target": "_blank",
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-urlContent sp-card-lookupInlineValues sp-card-keyboard-focusable ",
                      "href": {
                        "operator": "+",
                        "operands": [
                          "&ID=",
                          "[$lookupIterator.lookupId]"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$lookupIterator.lookupValue]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to use groupProps and want to group it by status field.

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Check example given [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-gallery-formatting#build-custom-group-headers) for using groupProps with gallery layout customizations.

Comment: That's not very helpful. I this specific to my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 196,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "groupProps":{}
  "formatter": {}
}
```